# Print multiple (not all) elements in an Arraylist on new lines Java

Tags: java, arraylist, println

I'm trying to print a few of the results at a time and line break to prevent passing the 80 character column in output. I don't want to use a hard-coded line value and would rather print out a few elements at a time until complete. The Arraylist is a value in a map, so for each word i'd like the output to look like this

word = 
[ 12, 456, 345, 134,

536, 6346, 3426, 2346,

2346, 2347, 36787, 46789]

rather than this:

word = [12, 456, 345, 134, 536, 6346...

Class involved:

```
package java112.analyzer;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *  This is the KeywordAnalyzer class. <br>
 *
 *@author mgundrum
 *
 */
public class KeywordAnalyzer implements Analyzer {

    private Map<String, List<Integer>> keywordMap = new TreeMap();
    private Properties properties;
    private int tokenOccurence = 1;

    /**
     *This is a constructor method for the TokenCountAnalyzer class
     */
    public KeywordAnalyzer() {

    }

    /**
     *This is a constructor method for the TokenCountAnalyzer class
     *
     *@param properties     The properties object passed from AnalyzeFile
     */
    public KeywordAnalyzer(Properties properties) {
        this.properties = properties;
        readFile();
    }

    public Map<String, List<Integer>> getKeywordMap() {
        return keywordMap;
    }

    public void readFile() {
        BufferedReader input = null;

        try {
            //create a BufferedReader to read the input file
            input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(properties.getProperty("file.path.keywords")));
            String inputLine = "";

            //loop through the input file one line at a time and split on white
            while (input.ready()) {
                inputLine = input.readLine();
                keywordMap.put(inputLine, new ArrayList<Integer>() );
            }
        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
            System.out.println("Failed to read input file");
            fnfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println("General Error");
            exception.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            //Don't forget to close!
            try {
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (java.io.IOException ioe) {
                System.out.println("Failed to close input file");
                ioe.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  This method counts the total tokens as they are passed in
     *
     *@param  token - tokens passed from AnalyzeFile
     */
    public void processToken(String token) {       
       if (keywordMap.containsKey(token)) {
           List list = keywordMap.get(token);
           list.add( new Integer(tokenOccurence));
           keywordMap.put(token, list);
       }
       tokenOccurence++;
    }
    /**
     *  This method defines the TokenCount output file.
     *
     *@param inputFilePath - original file
     */
    public void writeOutputFile(String inputFilePath) {
        PrintWriter output = null;

        try {
            output = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter(
                     properties.getProperty("output.dir") + 
                     properties.getProperty("output.file.keywords"))));

            for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : keywordMap.entrySet()) {
               output.println(entry.getKey() + " = ");
               output.println(entry.getValue());
               output.println();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println("FileWriter caused an error");
            ioException.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this static method that takes in a string and returns it word wrapped to a specified character length. I tested some basic edge cases, but you probably want to test it more thoroughly before you use it for anything!

In essence, it starts at the char length, then goes back to look for spaces. If it finds one, it replaces it with a newline. If it cant find any, it looks forward for them. If it fails that too, it gives up and returns whatever it has.

Here it is:

```
public static String wordWrap(String rawInput, int maxLineLength) {
        StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder(rawInput);
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

        while(input.length() > maxLineLength) {
            for(int i = maxLineLength; i >= 0; i--) {
                //you can change this delimiter to whatever (or add it as an argument =D)
                if(input.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                    output.append(input.substring(0, i));
                    output.append('\n');
                    input.delete(0, i+1);
                    break;
                }

                if(i == 0) {
                    for(int j = maxLineLength; j < input.length(); j++) {
                        if(input.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                            output.append(input.substring(0, j));
                            output.append('\n');
                            input.delete(0, j+1);
                            break;
                        }

                        if(j == input.length() - 1) {
                            return output.append(input).toString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return output.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This looks useful. However I was hoping to just print out a few of the elements from the array list at a time without having to mess with formatting too much. Is there a way to simply print a set number of elements from the list, line break, and then write again until the list is complete?

Comment: You could keep track of how many characters you print out, and insert a newline whenever you exceed a set amount. Would that work for you?

Comment: I could probably do that. I was hoping there was a way to simply iterate and print a few results from the array at a time. Thanks for the tip though